Why are sportsmen not desirous to have others of their persuasion move in?
In Jane Austen's Sense & Sensibility, when Sir John Middleton lets the Dashwoods move into his cottage, there's a comment about sportsmen (hunters) not wanting to "...[encourage] their taste":

In shewing kindness to his cousins, therefore, he had the real satisfaction of a good heart; and in settling a family of females only in his cottage, he had all the satisfaction of a sportsman; for a sportsman, though he esteems only those of his sex who are sportsmen likewise, is not often desirous of encouraging their taste by admitting them to a residence within his own manor.
Sense & Sensibility, chapter 7

I'm not too familiar with the culture around hunting in the nineteenth century. What does this mean that they don't want to "encourage their taste" by having them move in? If these sportsmen only respect men who similarly hunt, why would they be generally averse to having other sportsmen move in?

A given estate of land has a limited supply of game, and so if Sir John leased a residence on his estate to another sporting gentleman, the two of them would have to divide the sport between them.
Legally speaking, Sir John could have leased the residence only, denying the hypothetical tenant the right to shoot or fish on the rest of the land, but possibly he would have considered that ungenerous and ungentlemanly. In Pride and Prejudice, one of the ways in which Darcy demonstrates generosity is by inviting Gardiner (who is not even a tenant, but a visitor) to fish the streams on the Pemberley estate:

The conversation soon turned upon fishing; and she [Elizabeth Bennet] heard Mr. Darcy invite him [Gardiner], with the greatest civility, to fish there as often as he chose, while he continued in the neighbourhood, offering at the same time to supply him with fishing tackle, and pointing out those parts of the stream where there was usually most sport.
Jane Austen (1813). Pride and Prejudice, chapter 43. Project Gutenberg.

The idea in the other answer, that Sir John has some kind of design upon the Misses Dashwood, and wishes to keep them to himself, seems inconsistent with his character as portrayed in the novel, where he makes no attempt to prevent Colonel Brandon and Willoughby from paying court to Marianne. The novel makes it clear that the reason that the Middletons are so pleased to have the Dashwoods as tenants is that they need company to relieve the boredom of their rural life:

Sir John was a sportsman, Lady Middleton a mother. He hunted and shot, and she humoured her children; and these were their only resources. Lady Middleton had the advantage of being able to spoil her children all the year round, while Sir John’s independent employments were in existence only half the time. Continual engagements at home and abroad, however, supplied all the deficiencies of nature and education; supported the good spirits of Sir John, and gave exercise to the good breeding of his wife.
Jane Austen (1811). Sense and Sensibility, chapter 7. Project Gutenberg.


"...he would have considered [leasing the property without sporting rights] ungenerous and ungentlemanly" - More to the point, it would probably be hard to find tenants: who would want to spend time in a country cottage when they couldn't even take pot-shots at passing wildlife?
